# Testing controllers with services

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, dependency-injection, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I'm new to angular and unit-testing.

I have an application module `MyApp` including basic things an services, that are needed in all other modules, like service for logging `loggingService`

I also have an module for handling everything about map&geo-positon, called `MapModule` and I have an main module for application logic, called `MainModule`

The `MainModule` contains a controller, that I like to test: `messageSendCtrl`
The controller has some dependencies, like services from `MapModule`.

And: `MainModule` and `MapModule` has dependencies to the `MyApp`, because the `loggingService`is needed everywhere.

The code looks like that (pseudo-code):

***MyApp***

```
var MyApp = angular
        .module('MyApp', ['ngRoute','MainModule','MapModule']);

MyApp.service('loggingService', function (one, two) {
   [..] /*logging data somewhere for debugging application*/
});
```

***MainModule***

```
var MainModule = angular
        .module('MainModule', []); 
MainModule.controller('messageSendCtrl', 
    function($scope,$http, $location, locationService, loggingService) {
[...]
});
```

***MapModule***

```
var MapModule = angular
        .module('MapModule', ['uiGmapgoogle-maps']);
MapModule.service('locationService', function (loggingService) {
[...]
```

What I like to test is the `messageSendCtrl` from the  `MainModule`.  (probably) I was able to inject the location service into the test environment. But injecting the `locationService` was not successful.

Probably because `locationService` also uses the  `loggingService`.

Running the test results in

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: loggingServiceProvider <- loggingService <- locationService
```

My test looks like that:

```
describe('saving a document', function() {

  beforeEach(module('MainModule'));
  beforeEach(module('MyApp'));
  beforeEach(module('MapModule'));

  describe ('messageSendCtrl', function () {
    var scope,ctrl,locationService,loggingService; 

    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller,_locationService_,_loggingService_) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        ctrl = $controller('messageSendCtrl', 
                    {$scope: scope,
                     locationService: _locationService_,
                     loggingService : _loggingService_ });
    }));


      it('should actual not saved', function(){
        expect(scope.result).to.equal('unsaved');
    }); 
  })
});
```

So who can I solve the dependencies? Or is there an design problem at my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are multiple things going on, let's check it one by one:

1. at your test, you don't need do load all your modules, load just that module, that you want to test, your ctrl is in your MainModule, so use just 
   `beforeEach(module('MainModule'));`
2. every module should declare its dependencies, so your MainModule declaration should look like this: `var MainModule = angular.module('MainModule', ['MyApp']);` because one of your controller in your MainModule dependent on a service that is in an other module (MyApp)
3. it is easier to test if one module do just one thing, so if you have a logging service, make a logging service module for that, and include that module where you want to use logging.
   So don't make modules that is responsible for several different things, because if an other module need logging, that module will get every other service that your "godmodule" contains, and that makes difficult to test, and find bugs.

Comment: Number 1  & 2. That's it! Thank you! Number 3: nice to know.